# Integrating Angular Google Maps in Angular 4: Page reload error

Tags: angular, angular-google-maps

I am working with Angular 4 and Angular Google Maps.

I followed the instructions in [the getting started page](https://angular-maps.com/guides/getting-started/), but everytime I reload the page while I am on the map view, I get the error: `You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.`

This is the implementation of my code:

- map.component.html

```html
<div class="container">
  <agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
    <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
  </agm-map>
</div>
```

- map.component.ts

```html
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Component({
        selector: 'app-map',
        templateUrl: './map.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
    })
    
    export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
    
        private lat: number = 2.3522;
        private lng: number = 48.8566;
    
        constructor() { }
    
        ngOnInit() {
        }
    
    }
```

- app.module.ts

```html
//...
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';
//...
import { MapComponent } from './map/map.component';
//...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  //...
  MapComponent
  ],
  imports: [
  //...
  AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: MY_KEY
  }),
  //...
  ],
  providers: [
  //...
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Note that I don't have this error if I navigate to the map view from another view, but everytime I reload the page while I am on the map view, the error is shown in the browser console.

Comment: Does the error effect the functionality / does the page still load? Also, just to be sure, you're not using a router or anything that changes the URL right? When you reload the page, its reloading from the same url in the browser? Or is this on a local production build?

Comment: @diopside When I have this problem the page doesn't load, I access my map view only when I navigate to another view and then return to the map. And yes the page is reloaded from the same url in the browser. This happens either if I reload manually or when the angular-cli rebuild automatically the application in the dev environment and reload the page in the browser

Comment: @diopside Concerning routing, I don't use anything special: `{path: 'map', component: MapComponent`

Answer (score 0):

Please review the discussion in the link. This seems to be similar the problem you are facing but with ng2 though. It might point to you the right direction

https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/issues/315

Comment: Based on the link that you provided, I tried to lazy-load my map component but I still got the same error (For implementing the lazy-load module, I based my development on [this example](https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/ngmodule/pre-shared.3.eplnkr.html) )